# How to select only specific columns when querying using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know if we want to select only some specific columns by using find or where is like this.

```
Post.find(10).select("column1")
```

But, when I write code like this `post.user.username` (rely on ActiveRecord associations), if I want to select only a few columns from the `user` table, I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: You could always load them by yourself: `User.where(post_id: post.id).select('first_name, last_name')`

Comment: Yes, it is. But when using code like this post.user.username (rely on ActiveRecord associations), I don't see any way to specify column names.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you don't find the way at all. This is not a very common use-case for associations, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post model you can define the association as follows:

```
belongs_to :user, :select => [:username]
```

Then referring to the user via a post would select only the stated columns.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way I can customize the column name in the controller level?

Comment: I don't think so... you can just create an association just for that controller and use it only there, like: `belongs_to :user_for_posts_controller, :select => [:username], :class_name => "User"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use select options

to select the user name of all the posts

```
Project.select(["id", "name"])
```

with a where condition

```
Project.select(["id", "name"]).where("id=1")
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Post.find_by_sql("select * from posts P inner join users U on U.id = P.user_id where U.id = 10").collect{|x| x.<column_name>}
```